# Selecting an item from a dropdown doesnt trigger any action with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, dropdown

I'm trying to automate loading data using vb.net, but there comes a point where I select values of various combobox. Seeing the code of the page I find that the combobox has a format similar to this(its just an example):

```html
<select id="BirthMonth" name="BirthMonth">
<option value="">Month</option>

<option value="01" >January</option>

<option value="02" >February</option>

<option value="03" >March</option>

<option value="04" >April</option>
```

fails to work with `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById ("Name combo")` `SetAttribute ("OPTION", "March")`, searching the Internet I found a solution where inter is a parameter that contains the value.:

```
    Public Sub selector(ByVal inter)
    Dim option_ As HtmlElementCollection
    option_ = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("option")

    For Each option__ As HtmlElement In option_

        If option__.InnerHtml = inter Then

            option__.SetAttribute("selected", "True")

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

which if you choose value, but the page does not take it, so it does not refresh the other `Combobox`.

Anyone know how to do to select the value, so the page can trigger the action?

PS: must be in the name of the field by value.

Thank you very much
Bye!

PS: I solved the problem just adding this lines after the selection:

```
WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = True
        WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved just adding this lines after the selection:

```
WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = True
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```